# Get embedded youtube video duration without api

Tags: javascript, youtube

In my InfinityFree website, i have iframe element with Youtube embedded video

I want get the video info such as: duration + current timestamp of playing video

I tried using Youtube api, but i found that InfinityFree blocked Youtube api in free plan,

Any other ideas how get the video info?

Comment: You do more than [10,000 requests per day](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) to [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I take it as OP is hosting a FREE website at InfinityFREE and their FREE plan somehow blocks the Youtube API.